# ASP.NET VB Insert query

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, ms-access

I have an access Database and I am trying to insert records into. This seems like it would be very simple to do and for the most part all the code I have makes sense. I can create queries in VS 15 and they insert into my database, but for some reason my function to insert the records is not working. Can someone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
Private Function SendData(eData As String)
    Dim connectString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=|DataDirectory|web407db.mdb"

    Dim cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectString)

    cn.Open()

    Dim selectString As String = "INSERT INTO users(encryptID, firstName, lastName, userName, password, email) VALUES ('" & GetHash(eData) & "', '" & fName_in.Text & "', '" & lName_in.Text & "', '" & uName_in.Text & "', '" & pWord_in.Text & "', '" & email_in.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(selectString, cn)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cn.Close()
    Return True
End Function
```

The function gives me an unhandled exception on the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

Here is the stack trace

---

> [OleDbException (0x80040e14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.] 
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr) +1130764
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult) +247
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult) +208
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult) +58
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +162
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +107
>   WebAppUOP.About.SendData(String eData) in
>   c:\users\debuwa\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\WebAppUOP\WebAppUOP\AddContact.aspx.vb:41
>   WebAppUOP.About.SubmitContact() in c:\users\debuwa\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\WebAppUOP\WebAppUOP\AddContact.aspx.vb:26
>   WebAppUOP.About.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\users\debuwa\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\WebAppUOP\WebAppUOP\AddContact.aspx.vb:12
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9669962
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +108
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +12
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3562

`

Comment: Put your exception details here.

Comment: any password for database and what kind of exception /error your getting

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: @DezOnlyOne, Pls check your table name, column name, column data type, and column mapping it is correct.

Comment: Yes, they are correct. When I run the query in visual studio it updates fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I removed the password entry. I am not totally sure why I was not able to use password as a column name, but I removed it and now the app works fine. Thanks everyone for their help

Answer (score 0):

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

```
Protected Sub btn_sub_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_sub.Click
    Dim str As String
    Dim ans As String
    Try
        str = "insert into login values('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, cn)
        ans = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        MsgBox("Data Insert ")
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Insert the data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).